# APNS Push notifications: always receiving invalid token error

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm always receiving the *invalid token* error-response packet when trying to send a push notification to a certain device token.

That device token is provided by Apple's server (in production) and I'm sending the push notification using the production endpoint as well.

What other reasons can exist to receive that error, besides using a device token provided by the sandbox/production environment and contacting the wrong server when sending the notifications?

Comment: But you did not provide any info  what service are you using.  Your own made backend, or some existing service which would take token and then send push to it?

you probably have incorrectly formatted it.

Comment: @Guntis I'm using the FeedbackService implemented by javapns library

Comment: Hope you have configured the production push notification SSL certificate in your server (from where you are sending the message to APNS). Because, for a production profile signed application, we should have the production SSL certificate in server side.

Comment: Please post the code where you get the token and send it to your server.

Comment: I'm only doing the backend part, the app is external and contacts the provider (me) sending me the device token which I then register in the DB. I've checked with the app's dev that the code they receive is the same I'm storing in the DB.
I'd like to notice that this has already been working before and stopped working suddenly. Hence, my question regarding what can be causing the invalid token besides tokens belonging to different environments.

Comment: This is strange!! Is it the scenario that the push notification certificate had expired and Dev Team have renewed the same but you still have the old one?